# Mysql Import - CSV Files gets bigger and bigger

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, undo

I am a beginner when it comes to mysql. I am currently importing a .csv File which is 90GB big.

After 48hrs the data is according to my database 195GB big (C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\Database) and I also have a ungo_log File which is around 45GB.

Can somebody explain me what the undo_log File is for and why does the csv file become so big?

Also I am running out of space since I thought I can do the import on my SSD. Is there a way to continoue the import on another disk?

Thanks

Comment: *and why does the csv file become so big?* Why CSV? database... The amount of disk space occupied by the database is never equal to imported data size. For example, the indices, which are absent in CSV and are created during import needs in additional disk space...

Comment: Have a look at how to shrink the database. The log file is a transaction log for recovery. Depending on how you are doing your updates you might have a lot of wasted space. But as @Akina says, you would never expect your database to be the same size as the csv. It could be smaller or larger (usually larger) depending on what sort of compression is done.